# Why are there two different pages for questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, question-lists, navigation, homepage

**After over one day idle, this question/feature request does not seem to have drawn any attention. Maybe I failed to make clear my point of why this is important?**

This is a website with far more rules and etiquette than the related fora. It is also a place where people strictly enforce the rules. And lastly, it is a place that drastically differ both in concept and in design from those fora. **This differences create some sort of learning curve to use the site correctly**, and *people is more prone to make mistakes when they do not understand the system*. Thus, making the system simpler should reduce the learning curve and in turn reduce the number of mistakes from people.

**I say this change would make the system simpler because it would eliminate duplicated content** (for example, the "featured" questions, and the FAQ link is twice in the page) **and merge the non-duplicated, but highly related content** (in the end, it's about the list of questions).

**It would make it simpler also because it would make it more obvious**: right now, I do not know of any way of accessing the "interesting" questions if it's not by going directly to `http://www.stackoverflow.com/`. An "interesting" tab would make the link obvious to the vast majority of the users. It is not obvious either how the "hot" questions list differ from the "active" list or the "votes" list. I believe there could be more merging there. The "week" and "month" tabs could also be eliminated or moved as a filter for any of the other categories (i.e., the hottest of the month, or the most voted of the week, etc.)

### I would really like to hear what you think about this.

**Original post**:

I could not find any discussion about this here:

The page shown at `http://stackoverflow.com/` will show you "top" questions:

[image]

while `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` will show you all questions:

[image]

What is the rationale for that? It would seem more logical to add an "interesting" tab to the "all questions" page:

http://i56.tinypic.com/2qi47lx.png

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of is

- First page - https://stackoverflow.com/ is static page generate every few seconds(or ms), probably could serve several thousands (millions?) requests per second.
- Question page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions probably less cached and sql queries could also be involved, handle less requests per seconds than front page.

Comment: +1 That does make sense to reduce servers load, but I still think it would be easy to solve that issue: the front page could still show the same top questions but then have a tab link instead of the button above to the complete list in /questions.

Comment: It'd be _interesting_ to know what makes them 'interesting'; it's not keyed on votes, views, or answers, going by the screenshot.

Comment: *Interesting* also displays a question for longer than the questions on *questions* page. Maybe it filters according to activity/inactivity? + *interesting questions* have more yellowness, thus more interesting to me. *questions* doesn't filter on my the basis of *my* tags.