# How to Reach / Recognize "Top Questions"

Tags: support, questions, tag-watching, top-questions

Above the list of questions I'm viewing in stackoverflow, I noticed the title is "Top Questions."  There is also a tab selected that says "interesting."

It is indeed interesting, because I have no recollection of this "feature" existing in stackoverflow.  I then select the "Questions" button, and the title changes to "All Questions."  In an effort to understand "Top Questions," I search in vain to discover where the "Top Questions" button is to be found.  I hunt through almost every button or link I can select, and none will bring up that "mode" again.  The only way I'm able to return to "Top Questions" is by using my browser back button.

So I'm wondering two things:

1. How does a stackoverflow user intentionally reach "top questions".  What option is selected?
2. What defines or determines "top questions"?  What defines those questions that are "interesting"?

Comment: Or go back to the root: http://stackoverflow.com/. I believe the 'interesting' questions have to do with your favourite or excluded tags. Also, potentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86133/why-are-there-two-different-pages-for-questions

Answer (score 2):

It's the homepage: either visit http://stackoverflow.com or click on the logo on any page.

Interesting questions are determined by an [algorithm](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) designed for you—note that the Interesting tab is only available for Stack Overflow and no other Stack Exchange site. It's called "Top Questions" instead of "All Questions" because it just lists the most important questions, and doesn't paginate through all of them.